# Is there any way to update div according to failure and success of form remote in grails?

Tags: ajax, forms, grails, gsp

I am using form remote to submit form. If successfully data is saved means i want to update list div. If failed means i want to refresh error div. Is there any options in formRemote Of grails ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [formRemote](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/formRemote.html) have options like `onFailure`, `onSuccess` and `onComplete`.

```
<g:formRemote name="saveData" url="[controller: 'book', action: 'byAuthor']" onComplete="jQuery('#completeDivId').html(data)" onSuccess="jQuery('#successDivId').html(data)" onFailure="jQuery('#failureDivId').html(data)">
    ...
</g:formRemote>
```

Answer (score 0):

If these divs are different you have to use javascript events, in that case add onSuccess and onFailure parameters to the form:

```
<g:formRemote name="myForm" onSuccess="successFunction" onFailure="failureFunction" url="...">
</g:formRemote>
```

If the div is the same you can set the id of the div using the update parameter of the formRemote tag:

```
<g:formRemote name="myForm" update="updateMe" url="...">
</g:formRemote>
<div id="updateMe">this div is updated with the result of the byAuthor call</div>
```

See the [grails formRemote docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/formRemote.html) for more examples.